# Finding all unique subsets in array

Tags: c, algorithm, subset

I have an array containing n integers and I need to print every unique subset.
For instance,if my array {1,1,1,2},the output should be

```
1,  
1,1,  
1,1,1,  
2,  
1,2,  
1,1,2,  
1,1,1,2,
```

I have been able to print all possible subsets using binary shift,but I am stuck on removing duplicates.I have tried to save printed subsets to another array and comparing them,but that is wasting a lot of memory.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ( int argc, char * argv [] ) {
int numbers[4] = {1,1,1,2};
int n = 4;
int np = 1<<n;
int i;
int bitv;
int pos;
for (i=1; i<np; i++){
bitv = i;
pos = 0;
while (bitv > 0){
    if ((bitv & 1) == 1) printf("%d,",numbers[pos]);
    bitv >>= 1;
    pos++;
   }
  printf ("\n");
 }
return 0;
}
```

and the output:

```
1,  
1,  
1,1,  
1,  
1,1,  
1,1,  
1,1,1,  
2,  
1,2,  
1,2,  
1,1,2,  
1,2,  
1,1,2,  
1,1,2,  
1,1,1,2,
```

Comment: What are you trying for removing duplicates?  What do you mean by "save printed subsets"?

Comment: You need to accumulate your answer set into a storage structure of some type. When you add a new combo, have the adder check to see if that combo is already in place, and if so, just return, otherwise stuff in your new combo. When you are done generating your results, output the contents of your storage.

Comment: Probably the easiest way to do that would be to generate a string holding the combo, and then you can walk your storage structure on store to make sure you don't already have that string.

Comment: Those are technically not sets. Lists would be a better description. Is your given list known to be sorted? If it is, you could look first at sublists of length 1, then length 2, and so on. Detecting duplicates would be easy in that case.

Comment: Well,I guess you're right,I'm not a native speaker.I sort the array in descending order,then I start printing all possible lists.

Comment: If you are allowed to sort, then order doesn't matter, and perhaps multiset is a better name. And in that case, subset rather than sublist makes more sense. For example, is {1,2} equivalent to {2,1}? And is {1,3} a subset of {1,2,3}?

Comment: Yes, {1,2} is equivalent to {2,1},this is what I would like to avoid as well and {1,3} is a subset of {1,2,3}

Answer (score 3):

You can reframe this problem in a different way that might make it easier to solve. Instead of treating this as finding subsets of a master set, suppose that you have a frequency histogram of the number of times each element appears. For example, the set {1, 1, 1, 2} would be represented as { 1 → 3, 2 → 1 }. You can list all subsets by listing off the pairs

- (0, 0), meaning "zero 1's and zero 2's"
- (1, 0), meaning "one 1 and zero 2's"
- (2, 0), meaning "two 1's and zero 2's"
- (3, 0), meaning "three 1's and zero 2's"
- (0, 1), meaning "zero 1's and one 2"
- (1, 1), meaning "one 1 and one 2"
- (2, 1), meaning "two 1's and one 2"
- (3, 1), meaning "three 1's and one 2"

This gives a simple an elegant way to list off all the subsets without listing any duplicates. The overall algorithm would then be

- Construct the frequency histogram, perhaps by sorting the array and getting totals of all the elements in the array.
- List all n-tuples of integers corresponding to choices of the number of copies of each element from the original array.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

count the number of each digit ie: "histogram" the input array. 
and then use nested loops (or a varialble radix counter) to iterate through the options.

if your input is unconstrained, first sorting the array using qsort may help.

Answer (score 0):

Does the output order matter? If not, I have a dfs solution.

If the input array is unsorted, sort it first. In each layer, deal with one element(from 0 to n times, n is the appeared times of that element in the array).

```
initial                    []
               /      /         \                 \
have 1?    []      [1]         [1 1]            [1 1 1]
          /  \     /  \         /  \            /     \
have 2?  []  [2] [1]  [1 2] [1 1] [1 1 2]  [1 1 1] [1 1 1 2] 


vector<vector<int> > subsetsWithDup(vector<int> &S) {
    vector<vector<int>> result;
    vector<int> path;
    sort(S.begin(),S.end());
    dfs(result,S,path,0);
    return result;
}

void dfs(vector<vector<int>> &result, const vector<int> &S, vector<int> &path, int idx) {
    if(idx == S.size()) {
        result.push_back(path);
        return;
    }
    int next = idx+1;
    while(next < S.size() && S[next] == S[next-1])
        next++;
    dfs(result,S,path,next);
    for(int i = 1; i <= next-idx; i++) {
        path.push_back(S[idx]);
        dfs(result,S,path,next);
    }
    path.erase(path.end()-(next-idx),path.end());
}
```

Comment: that doesn't look like C to me.